# Convert Gradle/Kotlin project to Android Project

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I created a kotlin project with the command `gradle init`, which I can build and run without issues. I know AndroidStudio uses gradle to build/deploy an android project. With this in mind, can i modify the generated kotlin project to also become an android project? I want that when `gradle build` is issued, an `apk` file is generated, instead of the `jar` being generated right now. And, if possible, being able to deploy the `apk` to the phone connected to the computer (either via usb or wi-fi).

Answer (score 0):

You actually can, just add the AGP (Android Gradle Plugin) to your `build.gradle` script.

And from there, structure your project to as Android Project.

Of course it's like manual type of doing it, It's easier just to start an Android Project from Android Studio cause it will generate all the files needed for Android Project.

Comment: `gradle init`ask if i want `Split functionality across multiple subprojects?` could I do this conversion if I answer no to this question? I notice the android studio create a project with multiple subprojects. Do I can do this only adding the plugin and dependencies related to the android, modifying the `App.kt` class to `MainActivity.class`? I notice `gradle init` create a `resources` directory. I just rename this to `res' and create the same sub-directories present in the project created with android studio, or I could add all the funcionality from this XML files on the Kotlin code?

Comment: Also, when I add `android.useAndroidX=true` to my `settings.gradle` file, I got the error: `Could not get unknown property 'android' for settings 'HelloKotlin' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings`

Comment: To answer your original question, of course you can. But there's some stuff that you must configure first because android project doesn't have quite the same structure as plain kotlin project.

Things like `android.useAndroidX=true` can you put later after you configure your android project to run. 

I recommend doesn't change the folder naming, because it'll mess with the Gradle Plugin. For more information about directory, you can read it here.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/android-project-folder-structure/

You can mark my answer accepted if it helps, thanks.